# python json.tool and unicode escape

Tags: python, json, unicode

If I pass a utf-8 encoded text file through `python -m json.tool`, cyrillic text turns to \u****

There are a lot of ways to handle it inside py-scripts but I also use python as handly json formatter (json.tool).

How do I get proper utf-8 encoded output?

I tried CMD.exe, powershell and MINGW bash

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem. It is the *correct* encoding for non-ASCII text in JSON.

Comment: never met this on linux

Comment: But this is a problem for non-english speaking users

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this is the *correct* encoding?  According to https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt the default encoding is UTF-8.